# Bitmap from Memstream of an SVG gives invalid parameter exception

Tags: c#

The last line of the following code gives the error "Parameter is not valid", when the original image is an SVG:

```
var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64String);
var memStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
//memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var imageObject = new Bitmap(memStream);
```

Help please. Thanks.

EDIT: The image for example I am using is the image of the first formula in the following page right under the Theoremsection:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with 'using' for memorystream to handle garbage collection by itself?

```
    var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64String);
    Bitmap m = ByteToBitmap(imageBytes);

    public static Bitmap ByteToBitmap(byte[] imageByte)
    {
    using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
         mStream.Write(imageByte, 0, imageByte.Length); // this will stream dataand handle image length by itself
         mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

         Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream);
         return bm;
       }
    }
```

For SVG,

```
public static Bitmap ByteToBitmap(byte[] imageByte)
{
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(imageByte))
   {
    var s= SvgDocument.Open(mStream);
    var bm= svgDocument.Draw();
    return bm;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but that didn't fix the problem. Still getting the same error.

Comment: that means your function is working. maybe your source maybe empty. can you tell what is your imageBase64String when you log in terminal?

Comment: No the source is not empty. It is something like PHN2ZyB4bWxuczp4bGl.......jwvc3ZnPg==

Comment: okay. C# image library doesn't support svg format. You have to use third party library to be able to convert svg file type to others.install this library 'https://github.com/vvvv/SVG'  from github using nuget terminal

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you so much. Didn't know that.